# Repository Pattern with QueryDSL expressions: Create QueryDSL implementation for a backend

Tags: jakarta-ee, repository-pattern, specifications, querydsl

I've a `Repository` interface:

```
public interface CrudRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends Repository<T, ID>
{
    Iterable<T> findAll(Specification<T>... specifications)
        throws RepositorySystemException;
}
```

I've one entity class: `Resource`, so I extend `CrudRepository`:

```
public interface IResourceRepository extends CrudRepository<Resource, String> { }
```

I've a ElasticSearch persistence system I want to store/search my `Resource` objects, so I've created one repository implementation for ElasticSearch:

```
public abstract class ElasticsearchRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> 
    implements CrudRepository<T, ID> { }
```

and then,

```
public class ResourceRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Resource, String>
     implements IResourceRepository
```

Up to here, nothing is stange. Now, I want that my repositories are able to handle with query or filter specifications in order to search on elasticsearch.

In order to do that, I'm specifying my expressions using `QueryDSL`:

```
QResource qr = QResource.resource;
Expression exp = qr.source.sourceId.eq("id").and(qr.channel.endsWith("case"));
```

I'd like to send this QueryDSL to my `findAll(...)` method repository, but I don't know how to do it...

I don't know if it's better to change the method signature in order to receive QueryDSL expressions, I don't know. However, Where do I need to do the transformation between QueryDSL expressions to concrete ElasticSearch filters...?

Answer (score 1):

For posterity, have a look at the following:

```
'QuerydslPredicateExecutor' interface (Spring-Data) and 'XXXXExpressions'
```

- [Advanced Spring Data JPA - Specifications and Querydsl](https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl#querydsl) <= very incisive.
- [QuerydslPredicateExecutor inerface @ Spring Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/querydsl/QuerydslPredicateExecutor.html)
- [Using Querydsl in Spring Data JPA](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-data/query-dsl-basic.html)
- [SQLExpressions data types @ QueryDSL](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-data/query-dsl-basic.html)